# How to open port 8085?

Tags: windows, port

I am trying to open port 8085 for a server and nothing seems to work.

I called my ISP and they said they do not block ports (except 25)
I removed my router and am plugged directly into the modem
I disabled my firewall

And yet, canyouseeme.org still tells me "Connection refused" or "Connection timed out" when I check it.

What else could be blocking this port?

I'm running Windows Vista over a cable internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to unblock the port in the Windows Firewall (If you are running it).

[Follow the guide here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall)

Then you need to forward the port from your router to your machine, take a [look here](http://portforward.com/).

Please try both of these as it sounds to me like it is being blocked at one of these two stages.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a bit silly but...do you have an application running and LISTENING on that port? I don't think canyouseeme.org works if there's no app listening on a particular port.

Answer (score 0):

- Is this a TCP or UDP port?
- Have restarted the service or server running *after* disabling the Windows Firewall and/or any other software firewalls?
- Can you access it locally, i.e. `telnet localhost 8085` assuming TCP
- Can you locally access it using the non-localhost, private ([RFC 1918](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt)) IP address, e.g. `telnet 192.168.1.1 8085` -- this IP address is the one normally available via `ipconfig`.
- Can you locally access it using your *public* IP address, e.g. `telnet 24.xxx.xxx.174 8085`?

[NetCat](http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139) can be a useful tool.